# Why can't I use a member function cmp in C++ sort()？

Tags: c++, gcc

I am making a class named `MyClass`, in which a member function uses C++ `sort()` function, and I pass another member function `cmp` to it as an argument.

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/* If I use this cmp for sort(), there is no error.
bool cmp(int& x, int& y) {
    return x < y;
}
*/

class MyClass {
public:
    /* Or I use this cmp, there is no error too.
    static bool cmp(int& x, int& y) {
        return x < y;
    }
    */

    // compile failed.
    bool cmp (int& x, int& y) {
        return x < y;
    }

    void mySort(vector<int>& v) {
        sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
    }
};
```

(I know the `cmp` function is redundant actually, but it doesn't matter for showing the error).
Then the compiler gives following error message:

```
In file included from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from Untitled.cpp:1:
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)]':
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:81:17:   required from 'void std::__move_median_to_first(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Compare) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1921:34:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1953:38:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Size = long 
long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)]'
Untitled.cpp:28:37:   required from here
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:143:18: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>::_M_comp) (...)'
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Value&, _Iterator) [with _Value = int; _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)]':
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1828:20:   required from 'void std::__unguarded_linear_insert(_RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1855:36:   required from 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1885:25:   required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1971:31:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)]'
Untitled.cpp:28:37:   required from here
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:215:11: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>::_M_comp) (...)'
  { return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Value = int; _Compare = bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)]':
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:133:48:   required from 'void std::__push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Distance = long long int; _Tp = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:237:23:   required from 'void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, 
_Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Distance = long long int; _Tp = int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:342:22:   required from 'void std::__make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1672:23:   required from 'void std::__heap_select(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; 
_Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1933:25:   required from 'void std::__partial_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1948:27:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Size = long 
long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>]'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)]'
Untitled.cpp:28:37:   required from here
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<bool (MyClass::*)(const int&, const int&)>::_M_comp) (...)'
  { return bool(_M_comp(*__it, __val)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I also find that if I make the `cmp` function static, or I move it outside the class, everything will be OK. Why does this happen? What is the difference between these `cmp` functions?

Comment: Because a non-static member function needs an object to be called on.

Comment: Because (non-static) member functions needs an object to be called on, and the `sort` function doesn't have an `MyClass` object so it's simply not able to call the function properly. Either make the comparison function `static` or learn how to use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Or since the default comparison is using less-than don't pass any function at all (i.e. `sort(begin(v), end(v))` only).

Comment: `sort` needs a callable object. In C++, referring to a member function (i.e. non-static) strips away any `this` pointer that could have been used and thus results in a plain member function pointer. Use `std::bind` to make that callable with a specific instance (i.e. `this`).

Comment: Member functions must be called with an object of the typ MyClass, but std::sort only works with functions that can bw called without an object.

Comment: Because a (non-`static`) member function can only be called in context of an object.  Such as `some_myclass.cmp(2,3)` or `some_object->cmp(2,3)`.    `std::sort()` is designed assuming the function supplied can be called as `cmp(2,3)` (without the context of an object).   Bear in mind that, within a non-static member of `MyClass`,  `cmp(2,3)` can (syntactically) be called, but that's only because there is an implicit `this` pointer, so `cmp(2,3)` is implicitly `this->cmp(2,3)`.

Comment: Also: Why is `void mySort(vector<int>& v)` a member of `myClass`?

Comment: you can bind the non-static member function before passing to the function by `std::bind(&MyClass::cmp, *this, _1, _2)` where `_1` and `_2` are placeholders declared from namespace `std::placeholders`

Comment: Thank you everyone, I know what is wrong~

Answer (score 0):

A non-static member function needs an object to called on. So in fact, `MyClass::cmp` function takes three arguments, the third one(in fact, it's the first one) is `this`.

A possible solution for your problem is using lambda expressions.
It could be written as follows.

```cpp
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [this](auto a, auto b){ return this->cmp(a, b);});
```

Or you could use `std::bind`.

```cpp
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(&MyClass::cmp, this, _1, _2));
```

Comment: the solution is to just add `static` to `cmp()`